# Facebook URL is not allowed by App Configuration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I am currently facing this issue when I am trying to share a link on facebook, The following error as follows:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I have done a number of researches on the following problems and solutions provided in this forum yet I am still facing the same issue.

***What I have done:***

1.) I have included in the meta tags at the head of the html

```
<meta property="og:url"  content="https://www.alwaysxciting.com"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Memory Game" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="A memory game, built for fun with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript." />
```

2.) Within my app setting: I have included in the URL in

a.) Basic:  1.) AppDomains: https://www.alwaysxciting.com
            2.) Website: SiteURL: https://www.alwaysxciting.com
b.) Advanced: 1.) Client OAuth Settings: Valid OAuth redirect URIs: https://www.alwaysxciting.com

3.) I have ensured that the App_ID is the same as well.

and this is the code that I have set for the facebook share function:

```js
 //Initialize Facebook UI
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId: '******',
     version: 'v2.5',
     status: true,
     xfbml: true
   });
 };

 //Activate Facebook SDK
 (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s);
   js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

 //Facebook Share Function
 document.getElementById('facebook').onclick = function() {

   FB.ui({
     display: 'popup',
     method: 'share',
     href: 'https://www.alwaysxciting.com',
   }, function(response) {});
 }
```

```html
<div id="facebook">
  <img src="lib/img/Congratulations/facebook.png" />
</div>
```

What else am I missing or rather what else has possibly gone wrong???

Furthermore, as I am still developing this: I am currently running on a localhost, Tomcat Server.

This is the error shown in the console log:

> ping?client_id=115183318876880&domain=127.0.0.1&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.faceboo…:1 Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: _“Furthermore, as I am still developing this: I am currently running on a localhost, Tomcat Server.”_ – and is your app _locally_ reachable under that domain name you specified in your app settings …? If not, and you use a completely different address to test your app, then of course it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

App Domain should be "alwaysxciting.com" only. But if you run on localhost, you need to add a Platform with "http://localhost:3000" (or whatever port you are using) and "localhost" as additional domain.

Comment: Does it mean that if I were to host it direct to the following site: https://www.alwaysxciting.com, instead of hosting it to the localhost server, it shouldn't be an issue? and in that sense, that the App Domain should still just be "alwaysxciting.com"

Comment: if you put it online on your domain, it should work, of course. for development on localhost, you have to add localhost.

Comment: Thanks!!got it to work, now is for facebook to review and accept the app